# Is there a way to make an USB 1.1 device be detected as an USB 2.0 device

Tags: usb

I have a USB 1.1 device, that I wish to use with a Corning optical USB extender. Corning's USB extender however does not support USB 1.1 devices. Is there any way of fooling it into thinking that the device on the oter side is USB 2.0. USB 2.0 uses additional handshake packets, would it be possible to emulate them without hooking up a microcotroller?

Comment: Do you already own the ridiculously expensive Corning cable? If not, look at USB repeaters, 30m for $£€30

Comment: Just for those who didn't look up the prices of these things…  30m  $£€350, 50m $£€500

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://www.corning.com/optical-cables-by-corning/worldwide/en/help.html#faqs) says:

> USB3.Optical cables by Corning are optimized to work in hi-speed (480Mb/s) and superspeed (5.0Mb/s) systems. The cable can support lower speed USB 1.1 & 1.0 peripherals (<12Mb/s) with use of a wall-powered intermediate hub (either USB2 or USB3).

So yeah, just use the hub you’d probably need anyway to provide power.

Comment: A USB 2.0 hub is more of a router and/or switch in networking terms.  The hub takes all the USB 1.1 packets and re-packs them into USB 2.0 packets, this is to make more efficient use of the bandwidth.  This is very clever as it means something like 4 USB 1.1 devices use the bandwidth of 1 USB 2.0 device rather than each grabbing their own slice of time on the cable.  I recall USB 1.1 has a single ended mode while USB 2.0 is only differential, so this gives the repacked USB 1.1 better noise resistance.

Answer (score -2):

The answer unfortunately is no. The cable itself is 'dumb', its the driver and usb interface which determine communication type.
You could try to downgrade the driver to a usb1.1 but I doubt you'll find a driver for that which is compatible with the usb interface hardware.

Comment: A USB extender that is optical is most certainly not dumb. It must at least contain electronics that convert electrical USB to optical and back again.

Comment: @DanielB In my understanding a dumb cable is one that doesn't understand what it is transmitting. Assuming the optical cable just converts the digital signals to optical and back I would still consider it a dumb cable but that depends on how you define "dumb".

Comment: @DanielB Does the cable contain a microprocessor?

Comment: (I didn’t downvote.) Maybe not a microprocessor, but definitely advanced active circuitry. USB 3.0 signaling is quite different from USB 2.0 and it has to detect which is used. There’s also replicating the state at the other end of the cable etc pp. USB 1.x has very different signaling voltage levels that the cable probably does not support. This isn’t about PC software, that much is clear.

Comment: @DanielB I disagree. The cable was made for one function, it carries out that function and only that function. It does not have the ability to change or alter its function in any way. Therefore it is 'dumb'.
To claim a cable is not 'dumb' is tantamount to saying a road is not 'dumb'.